# Array data values load correctly in simulator but returns Nil values on phone

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

Hello folks and thanks for your help,

I am currently running an Xcode 8 project using swift 3 and Firebase Database.  I am pulling over data from a CLLocationSearch using Core Location Data from a previous table Search UI.  The data comes over and populates the "StoreUI" where I have this function addBtn that kicks off the code below to send the data to Firebase Database.

My issue is as follows: When I run the app with xCode's simulator, everything works fine.  The data pulls together, fills the array properly, and when I break the code after setting up the array, I see all the proper values before it eventually posts to firebase.  Again, using the simulator everything works 100%.

However, when I run the app from the phone, nothing happens in the array.  All the values come back as nil for each segment resulting as 8 nil values in my array.  Because the array has nil values it will crash the app during the post command.

What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to do, to get this running correctly both in the simulator and the phone testing?

So far I tired moving the variable setup outside the function, but I get the same results.  I was thinking of moving the "let post" code into it's own function, but I am not sure that will help.

Thanks again for your help!

```
 @IBAction func addBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // Save Store Info.
    let uniqueRef = storeRef.childByAutoId()
    geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoRef)

    let lat = storeData?.placemark.coordinate.latitude
    let long = storeData?.placemark.coordinate.longitude

    let post : [String: String] = ["StoreName" : (storeData?.name)!,
                                   "subThouroughfare" : (storeData?.placemark.subThoroughfare)!,
                                   "Thouroughfare" : (storeData?.placemark.thoroughfare)!,
                                   //"subLocality" : (storeData?.placemark.subLocality)!,
                                   "locality" : (storeData?.placemark.locality)!,
                                   "subAdministrativeArea" : (storeData?.placemark.subAdministrativeArea)!,
                                   "administrativeArea" : (storeData?.placemark.administrativeArea)!,
                                   "postalCode" : (storeData?.placemark.postalCode)!,
                                   "phoneNumber" : (storeData?.phoneNumber)!
        ]

    let key: String = uniqueRef.key
    geoFire!.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!), forKey: key)

   uniqueRef.setValue(post)


}
```

Comment: What does the code look like where `storeData` gets populated?

Comment: The store data is populated through the segue.

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "storeDetailSegue" {
        let storeVC : storeViewController = segue.destination as! storeViewController
        
        storeVC.storeData = xStoreData
        }
        
    }

Comment: and it's setup in the storeViewController as 

var storeData : MKMapItem?

Comment: OK, back a step.  :)  How does `xStoreData` get its value?  (Or whatever the ultimate source of the object is named.)

Comment: xStoreData is a MKMapItem getting it from the storeSearchVC using core location and it is getting that data from CLLocalSearch query.

Comment: `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let storeData = matchingItems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        xStoreData = storeData

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "storeDetailSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    
}`

Comment: My 3rd party developer may have fixed the issue.  I will need to test it. now.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with coding my 3rd party developer did, having issues with the MKMapItem.  He has fixed my issue and this case is closed.

Comment: This really isn't an answer that will help anyone in the future. You should delete the whole question.